# Connect a sub-model with multiple outputs to current model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, feature-class, iterator

I have a model in model builder that is clipping multiple feature classes to my study area. It is running with an iterator and creating 4 new clipped feature classes that are only represented by one output in model builder. Now I am trying to add this model as a sub model to run further tools on the individual outputs from my sub model. My problem is that the sub model only has one output and any tool that I attach to it will run for each feature class that was created from the sub model. Is there a way to have the sub model show each individual clipped feature class to connect them to separate tools?

- For Clarity*

I'm currently running a bunch of clips to my study area at the start of my model that looks like this.

[image]

There area 4 feature classes being clipped in my data set. In an attempt to clean my model up, I created a sub model with an iterator to clip all those feature classes and it looks like this.

[image]

Now all my feature classes are run through the iterator, however, there is still only one output icon in the model. So I can not connect individual outputs from that iterator to the rest of the model. If I connect that final output, it will run the model for every layer that goes through the iterator.

[image]

The above model is showing how the sub model is represented in my current model, but only has one output icon and therefore I can't connect individual output features from the sub model to the current model.

Comment: Are you talking about integrating a model within a model: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007p000000 perhaps?  You need to perform different actions for each unique FC output?

Comment: Are you able to include a screenshot of the relevant part of your model, please?  I'm thinking that you probably need to look at [**Collect Values**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000005000000.htm) but its hard to tell from your brief description.

Comment: I have added some clarity and diagrams of my model. I hope my question makes more sense now.

Comment: you could try - model only tools - select data tool make your submodel a precondition to the select data tool and use this to select each data you then need to process

Comment: Would you be able to expand upon your comment as an answer with details like whether you have done this successfully, preferably a diagram to illustrate the technique you describe, and a link to the Select Data tool documentation for ready reference, please?

Comment: i have used select data before but i dont have the example to hand now. from memory you may need to have the feature classes present in the model as parameters to allow their selection by the select data tool. there is an example use of select data tool here. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00400000001m000000#ESRI_SECTION1_D2DFA72326C54E05B1CB2DAC24FCBCFC